# Explain purpose of `e` event parameter in onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some question, hope guys can answer me. In this following function, I can't understand event 'e'. What is the 'e'? how we call the function or where's the function called? Give me some example, please!

```
function my_on_edit(e) {
  var s = findSheetById_(e.gridId);
  var r = e.range;
  s.getRange(r.rowStart, r.columnEnd+1).setValue( s.getName() );
}

function findSheetById_(id) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  for( var i in sheets )
    if( sheets[i].getSheetId() == id )
      return sheets[i];
  throw 'Unable to find sheet with id: '+id;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Function `my_on_edit` is probably bound to onEdit trigger, check out [Google Script triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers). List of active triggers is available in script editor in `Resources` menu.

On each edit action on your spreadsheet this handler is called with edit event object passed. `e` contain fields:

```
{ 
    String user, 
    SpreadSheet source, 
    Range range,
    Object value 
}
```

You can find more detailed [description](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) at section "Spreadsheet Edit Events"

Comment: Thank you so much. But I get my_on_edit is a onEdit trigger, but it's a trigger so it active when the sheet was edited, so why we need event 'e'? what is the role of 'e'?

Comment: `e` is event data, google service gives you information what was changed, by who and what is new value of modified cell. You dont need to call event handler manually (but you can anyway).

Comment: Can you give me an example script show how we called e, please!

Comment: You are NOT supposed to call on edit trigger in code. If you really want you can, because its just a function. Pass any object which has same fields as in documentation. Check http://jsfiddle.net/5pLuh/

Comment: Thanks, you so kind-hearted to answer my question. I get it :)

Comment: @MDerks, can I replace 'e' with any alphabet letter?

Comment: @AndrewAnderson, yes you can

Answer (score 1):

You know, I had the same question: what was that "е" in `onOpen(e)`. I found an answer right there on Google website:

> The `e` parameter in the function names above is an event object that is  passed to the function.
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers.

And then they explain that the event object contains information about the context that caused the trigger to fire.