# Can i build an event object myself in Google Script App?

Tags: object, google-apps-script, eventtrigger

I bought a 3rd party google app script to use. However, it can only be called with onEdit method and their codes are private that i cannot make change. Also, what i need is based on time-trigger instead of onEdit-trigger. Thus, I tried to build my own event to trigger the function:

```
// This function work well and can call the 3rd Party App Script
// It is triggered by onEdit googlesheet, which works well
function funcOnEdit(e) {
  3rdPartyApp.funcOnEdit(e));
}
// Below is the jsontostring result of the event e
// {authMode:"FULL",oldValue:"false",range:{columnEnd:6,columnStart:6,rowEnd:3,rowStart:3},source:{},triggerUid:"xxx",user:{email:"xxxx@gmail.com",nickname:"xxxx"},value:"TRUE"}
```

So I build a similar event object which triggered by time to make it happened.

```
function funcOnTimeTrigger(e) {
   var e1 = {authMode:"FULL",oldValue:"false",range:{columnEnd:6,columnStart:6,rowEnd:3,rowStart:3},source:{},triggerUid:"xxx",user:{email:"xxxx@gmail.com",nickname:"xxxx"},value:"TRUE"};
   e1.triggerUid = e.triggerUid;
   3rdPartyApp.funcOnEdit(e1));
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find any document and reference code to build an "onEdit" event. Thats why, I tried find the object/class myself.

```
function getObjType(obj) {
  var type = typeof(obj);
  if (type === "object") {
    try {
      // Try a dummy method, catch the error
      type = obj.getObjTypeXYZZY();
    } catch (error) {
      // Should be a TypeError - parse the object type from error message
      // type = error.message.split(" object ")[1].replace('.','');
      type = error.message;
    }
  }
  return type;
}
// Below function is triggered by onEdit 
function funcOnEdit_checker(e) {
  getObjType(e);
}
// Unfortunately, it cannot show the object name or classname
```

I have no idea what to do next, may i know if it is possible to build an event class/object ourselves in Google Script App? Can anyone give some hints on how to do so? or it is not possible?

I want to create the event-obj "developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events" manually and pass the event "e" to 3rdPartyApp.funcOnEdit function. Is it possible to do so?

Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar) and then take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) and look at the Learn Apps   Script section after that you can dive into triggers and events section

Comment: thanks for your comment, i have read those doc before, and but i cannot create the event-obj "https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events" manually and pass the event to onEditfunc function, can u give more hints to me.

Comment: An event object is just an object so yes you can build your own event object.  You can figure out what's in it by using `function onEdit(e) {Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));}` and then trigger the function by making an edit.

Comment: this is what i tried and not work (the 2nd part of my code), however, it doesn't work. So I wonder if it is a class object, as event e 's value can be called with their function such as "e.range.getColumn()"

Comment: I've run onEdit(e) functions with my own event object.  It works.  Perhaps they need to be installabile in order to perform functions that require permission.

Comment: This what an event object for onEdit trigger looks like: `{"authMode":"FULL","range":{"columnEnd":1,"columnStart":1,"rowEnd":3,"rowStart":3},"source":{},"triggerUid":"trigger id","user":{"email":"your email","nickname":"your nickname"},"value":"77"}`

Comment: To run the onEdit() function with you own event object just call the onEdit(e) function from another function and pass the event object to it.

Comment: let me clarify, it works with JSON.stringify function (get from onEdit Func) which shown in 1st/2nd part of my code. However, i cannot pass to onEdit func when the event object is created by me manually (which triggered by on-time-trigger Func). so i doubt it is a class object with getColumn() or getRow() function

Comment: As I just said to run the onEdit(e) function just call it from another function and pass the event object to it. I don't think that they can tell that it's not been called by a trigger as long as the event object is there.

Comment: I think this is the part i have done in my 2nd part of my code? which i create event e1 and pass to onEdit func

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Cooper idea, who share same thought as me.

And finally I found the result @ [Explain purpose of `e` event parameter in onEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949277/explain-purpose-of-e-event-parameter-in-onedit)

Below is my answer (not yet optimized but work):

```
function funcOnTimeTrigger(e) {
  
  var e2 =  {}
  e2["authMode"] = ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL
  e2['user'] = "me";
  e2['range'] = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("XXXXXX").getRange(5,3).activate();
  e2.range.columnStart = 5;
  e2.range.columnEnd = 5;
  e2.range.rowStart = 3;
  e2.range.rowEnd = 3;
  e2['source'] = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  e2['oldValue'] = "old";
  e2['value'] = "new";
  
  // Run The Program
  3rdPartyApp.funcOnEdit(e2);
}
```